# I loaded a csv file and by default, it loads a particular column as X and another as Y. How is that X and Y selected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is the code I used to import the csv file:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['solar-energy-production-sites-1.csv'])) 
print(df)
```

When I printout X(or Y), one of the columns is taken without me declaring X as such. What causes it to take that particular column?

Comment: This is a standard pandas question, and it has nothing to do with `numpy` or `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a question like this, the documentation of the relevant module usually has the answer. In this case, the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), describes a `header` parameter in `read_csv()` that probably answers your question:

> **header** : *int, list of int, default ‘infer’*
>
> Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is to infer the column names: if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are inferred from the first line of the file, if column names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to header=None. Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names. The header can be a list of integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be skipped (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this parameter ignores commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.